# An error shown while saving C/C++ file in Code::Blocks

Tags: code-blocks

I have installed Code::Blocks from the Ubuntu store. I was trying to save C/C++ files, but it shows me the following problem. Are there any solutions?

[image: screenshot of assertion failure error message with Stop and Continue buttons and the ability to expand a backtrace]

> #### codeblocks
>
> An assertion failed!
>
> ../src/common/strconv.cpp(3018): assert "Assert failure" failed in
>   wxCSConv(): invalid encoding value in wxCSConv ctor

Comment: Looks like a bug in Code::Blocks. What happens if you select "continue"?

Comment: Perhaps installing a different version of Code::Blocks might avoid the problem altogether. In Ubuntu, it is available separately as both Snap and APT packages. I recommend that you **[edit]** this question with the output of `snap list codeblocks`, `apt list codeblocks`, and `type -a codeblocks` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a C++ project in Code::Blocks and then you will be able to add a .cpp file to your project and save it by following these steps.

1. Open Code::Blocks and select *File* -> *New* -> *Project* -> *Console application* -> click *Go* button -> C++ -> click *Next* button -> fill in title field -> click *Finish* button.
2. Find your new project in the right pane of Code::Blocks under the *Projects* tab.
3. Right-clock the project's name -> select *Add Files* -> main.cpp.

Create a C project in Code::Blocks and then you will be able to add a .c file to your project and save it by following the above steps 1-3, except replace C++ with C and replace main.cpp with main.c. If you run into a problem saving the .c file create a new C project from scratch and leave the *debug* and *release* options at the end unchecked.

When you're ready to add some code to main.cpp and main.c start off with the simple code shown below for printing "hello world" in the console until you've got the basic Code::Blocks navigation working.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this is because of your encoding settings.

Please follow the steps to resolve the error:-

1. Open Codeblocks
2. Click on settings
3. Open editor's setting
4. Now open encoding setting
5. Set UTF-8 as default settings

I hope it will be fixed.